# Better ways to create an interactive list?

Tags: list-view, custom-list

I have a custom list created on SharePoint which is being used by users to create requests.

The list has multiple one line Text columns and Check Boxes.

Users raise around 15-20 such request every day. I want to make it easier for them to raise these requests, as good amount of time is being sent in raising it.

Could someone please advise an easier and more interactive way to do it on SharePoint.
[image: Sample List]

Comment: I've given some ideas below about what could be done with SharePoint quite effortlessly, but this kind of questions could be answered more intensively on the [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). It's very recommend to exactly list or screencap the form to be filled if you are to ask a question in there about the same subject, as the answer is highly dependent on what steps the form consists of, and what are their input types & requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends also on the form's structure. If you e.g. have a checkbox for some question, which other questions are dependent of, you might want to have users to automatically skip some of the questions when the user doesn't tick the checkbox.

As an example:

> Question 1: "I want to have a sandwich with my coffee"
>
> --> Question 2: "Which fillings you'd want?"
>
> --> Question 3: "Do you have any allergies?"
>
> ----> Question 4: "Which allergies?"

Now if the user chooses not to tick the checkbox on Q1, the user won't have to answer the question 2-4. Although you could feel this generates additional questions from "Do you/Don't you?" --> "Which/What?", it's still way faster to finish a form which has only checkboxes than multiselect/free-form text fields.

This functionality is called **cascading**. You'll get a good overview of the subject, and multiple existing answers, by browsing the tag [cascading](/questions/tagged/cascading).

---

Additional things for you to consider:

- Do users input texts with only a few variations?

  - -> Use dropdown-box/radio-button checklist, or use managed metadata field which offers suggestions for input
- Do users input user names from your domain?

  - -> Populate the users straight from AD by using People-field instead of manually writing

Comment: Thank you Moe for your answer. 

I have attached a screenshot of how the list looks like. Cascading is not required here.  I expect Users to enter certain text values which are mandatory (environment, project, name etc) then there is a long list of  checkboxes, user will select whichever they want to run and then finally save it at the end.

Is there a better way to put this in a list?

Comment: @Sachin thanks for the detailing. I'm afraid I'm not able to give further help. This seems more about user experience/UI design than about SharePoint, because the problem seems to be at the long list of checkboxes. However, you - as the person who understands your domain the best - can only tell us externals if there exists any semantics, patterns and/or connections. Therefore it would be the best if you were able to tell us what is your goal, as it's next to impossible to figure it out by us.

Comment: My requirement is simple - The list has to have certain mandatory fields and then around 30 checkboxes, they can tick as many checkboxes as they want. There are no patterns or connections between these checkboxes, they all are individual streams and how many checkboxes (streams) are ticked is based on what a user want.

Comment: I think I need to change the way this form looks like. Given, I dont have access to SharePoint server, my options are limited. Probably I should look for a way to include a js script on sharepoint which can help me in creating a new list with different views (multiple columns in a single row), something like this.